# WebSocket url "ws" as prefix on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc, google-compute-engine

I need to create url like 
ws://serverurl:8080

how should I define this protocol on Google Compute Engine for my instance so that I can access websocket etc.

I am really stuck here. I need to wind this up.
Please reply,

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: Do you mean how to create a Websocket server? There a tons of options for many languages....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IanGSY,

Thanks for your reply,
I configured websocket over nodejs and pointed the url with prefix ws and it worked. I configured node in order to serve http and as well as ws.

for example if 
Http = http://example.com:8080
ws = ws://example.com:8080

and it started working ..

Previously my confusion was..actually I confused with GCE Console, as it gives us ability to configure firewall etc.

Thanks again.

Shashank